# How can I define a regex that matches multiple patterns anchored at the same position in my search text?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use Python's [findall](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.findall) to try and find all the hypenated *and* non-hypenated identifiers in a string (this is to plug into existing code, so using any constructs beyond `findall` won't work). If you imagine code like this:

```
regex = ...
body = "foo-bar foo-bar-stuff stuff foo-word-stuff"

ids = re.compile(regex).findall(body)
```

I would like the `ids` value to be `['foo', 'bar', 'word', 'foo-bar', 'foo-bar-stuff', and 'stuff']` (although not `bar-stuff`, because it's hypenated, but does not appear as a standalone space-separated identifier). Order of the array/set is not important.

A simple regex which matches the non-hypenated identifiers is `\w+` and one which matches the hypenated ones is `[\w-]+`. However, I cannot figure out one which does both simultaneously (I don't have total control over the code, so cannot concatenate the lists together - I would like to do this in one Regex if possible).

I have tried `\w|[\w-]+` but since the expression is greedy, this misses out `bar` for example, only matching `-bar` since `foo` has already been matched and it won't retry the pattern from the same starting position. I would like to find matches for (for example) both `foo` and `foo-bar` which begin (are anchored) at the same string position (which I think `findall` simply doesn't consider).

I've been trying some tricks such as lookaheads/lookbehinds such as mentioned, but I can't find any way to make them applicable to my scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're asking for overlapping regex, which python's `re` module does not currently support.  If you need to use the module, and your strings aren't that long, you could simply match twice

Comment: It's unclear why `foo`, `bar`, and `foo-bar` should all be matched from the first string, while you don't want a similar overlapping match for the second string. Is the number of hyphens a factor in the decision?

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/dXJUDE

Comment: Are you sure you want `bar` to be matched, but not `bar-stuff`? That does not appear to be consistent.

Comment: @tripleee Sorry I should have clarified earlier. It is consistent, but I appreciate it's confusing. `bar-stuff` is a hypenated *substring* of one of the identifiers, so it doesn't count by my criteria. Only non-hypenated substrings should count.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, but I think maybe I didn't explain clearly enough. Your regex includes the specific strings `foo`, `bar`, etc. Those were just examples. I'm looking for a generalized regex which does this for *all* identifiers.

Comment: It seems https://ideone.com/LpnAEX works as you expect. If you expect all hyphenated chunks, their first and last elements, this will work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's extremely close. If you can turn that into an answer, I'm happy to mark it as correct for now as it's definitely very close and perhaps sufficient for my purposes. However, unfortunately, if you add `foo-word-stuff` to my list of identifiers, it does not extract `word` (my bad for not making my test case more thorough).

Comment: Can you please explain the rules? I do not quite get it, thus, cannot provide an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the identifiers I want to find are both the entire space-separated "word" (including hyphens) or individual "subwords" (without any hyphens). So for `A-B-C D`, `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A-B-C']` is the correct answer, it should not include `A-B` or `B-C`.

Comment: Did you see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316209/3832970)? I think it fully answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = "foo-bar foo-bar-stuff stuff" #=> {'foo-bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo-bar-stuff', 'stuff'}
# s = "A-B-C D" # => {'C', 'D', 'A', 'A-B-C', 'B'}
l = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\w+(?:-\w+)*(?!\S)', s)
res = []
for e in l:
    res.append(e)
    res.extend(e.split('-'))
print(set(res))
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\S)` - no non-whitespace right before
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?:-\w+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?!\S)` - no non-whitespace right after.

See the [pattern demo online](https://regex101.com/r/YMWPp2/1).

Note that to get all items, I split the matches with `-` and add these items to the resulting list. Then, with `set`, I remove any eventual dupes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to mark this accepted for now especially given the effort you've put in - thanks! Unfortunately this isn't suitable for my purposes - I should have made this clearer in the question but I'm trying to plug my regex into some existing code that uses `findall` (and only findall) - yours augments it with a loop. I might be able to hack it in though. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier No idea if it is possible. See [another demo](http://rextester.com/WNJTX11169) (it is Python 2, I guess some things can be done better with Python 3.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) alone, since it finds all **non-overlapping** matches, as the documentation says.

All you can do is find all longest matches with `\w[-\w]*` or something like that, and then generate all valid spans out of them (most probably starting from their `split` on `'-'`).

Please note that `\w[-\w]*` will also match `123`, `1-a`, and `a--`, so something like
`(?=\D)\w[-\w]*` or `(?=\D)\w+(?:-\w+)*` could be preferable (but you would still have to filter out the `1` from `a-1`).

Comment: I had a nasty feeling that was the case, but thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use regex

Just use split(below is example)

```
result = []
for x in body.split():
    if x not in result:
            result.append(x)
    for y in x.split('-'):
            if y not in result:
                    result.append(y)
```

Comment: Reasonable approach, thanks. Doesn't answer my question with a regex, which is unfortunate as I'm trying to retrofit my answer into somewhere that uses one. But this is helpful, nevertheless. Thanks.